# Android Download Manager handling File Not found

Tags: android, android-download-manager

I am checking the documentation in http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/DownloadManager.html

but did not find the answer i am looking for. my question is, in case download manager received a URL to download a file from a server, and the URL file destination does not exist, what type of error does the Download Manager gives. is it ERROR_UNKNOWN or ERROR_FILE_ERROR..did anyone face this? thank you for your help

Comment: i just tried it my self and the status returned was STATUS_FAILED but with no reason! which is strange

Answer (score 3, accepted):

after testing this case, the Download Manager returns a STATUS_FAILED with DownloadManager.COLUMN_REASON 404.